# resizing std::vector to a value less than its initial reserve capacity erases data

Tags: c++

Can somebody explain why resizing a `std::vector` to a value less than its initial `reserve` capacity erases data contained in it before resizing. I am thinking `resize` just sets internal size variable to the given value(in this case from `0` to `2` no extra allocation if resize is less than capacity). What needs to be done if I want to retain data after resizing? This is a sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> vec_buff;
    vec_buff.reserve(32);
    
    vec_buff.data()[0] = static_cast<char>(0xA5);
    vec_buff.data()[1] = static_cast<char>(0xA6);
    
    std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<uint16_t>(vec_buff.data()[0]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<uint16_t>(vec_buff.data()[1]) << std::endl;
    
    vec_buff.resize(2);
    std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<uint16_t>(vec_buff.data()[0]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<uint16_t>(vec_buff.data()[1]) << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Resize before setting any data .... What is the purpose of this, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shown code results in undefined behavior.

```
vec_buff.reserve(32);
```

This sets reserve capacity for the vector. This ***does not*** set the size of the vector to 32 values. That's what `resize()` is for. This is not `resize()` but `reserve()`. The vector is still empty. There are exactly 0 values in this vector.

```
vec_buff.data()[0] = static_cast<char>(0xA5);
vec_buff.data()[1] = static_cast<char>(0xA6);
```

This uses `data()` to obtain an internal pointer to the vector. That has no values. Then this attempts to modify nonexistent values in the vector. `data()[0]` does not exist. Neither does `data()[1]`. Undefined behavior. You can no longer expect any meaningful results from the rest of your program.

If you want to "to retain data after (subsequent) resizing", then this vector should be `resize()`d in the first place.

Comment: "You can no longer expect any meaningful results from the rest of your program." - or indeed any part of the program *before* the undefined construct. Otherwise an upvote.

Comment: @Sam I have one doubt. As per my knowledge `reserve` allocates requested size  memory. So what is wrong in accessing that memory directly(vector's internal buffer memory) like the way I did?

Comment: Because since it is not a part of vector's defined contents, `std::vector`s algorithms are under no obligation whatsoever to preserve their existing contents, and may choose to scribble over them, for whatever reason they like. Which they apparently do, as part of the `resize()`. Which you've observed. The End. The only thing that reserving vector storage guarantees is that no reallocation will happen as long as the vector's total size does not exceed it's reserved size. There is no guarantee whatsoever that reserved, but not used, space will not be modified by `std::vector` at any time.